# Why am I getting a mile-long output file when transpiling jsx with webpack/babel?

Tags: webpack, babeljs, jsx

This is my first time trying to implement the babel transpiler (I'm using webpack), and according to everything I'm reading, a simple input file should give a relatively simple output file. Even according to [this testing site](https://babeljs.io/repl) the output I get is *very* simple compared to the output I'm getting in a real-world environment.

My input file is basically this:

```js
class Gallery extends Component{
    render(){
        console.log(front_end)
        return(
            <div class="gallery-container">
                {front_end.map(e=>{
                    return(
                        <div class='front-end'>
                            {e.name}
                        </div>
                    )
                })}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Gallery/>, $('#container')[0])
```

The output I'm getting on the site has a handful of functions at the time, and then very simply,

```js
var Gallery =
/*#__PURE__*/
function (_Component) {
  _inherits(Gallery, _Component);

  function Gallery() {
    _classCallCheck(this, Gallery);

    return _possibleConstructorReturn(this, _getPrototypeOf(Gallery).apply(this, arguments));
  }

  _createClass(Gallery, [{
    key: "render",
    value: function render() {
      console.log(front_end);
      return React.createElement("div", {
        class: "gallery-container"
      }, front_end.map(function (e) {
        return React.createElement("div", {
          class: "front-end"
        }, e.name);
      }));
    }
  }]);

  return Gallery;
}(Component);

ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(Gallery, null), $('#container')[0]);
```

When I try to do the same thing in my real-world application, I get long strings of code (even in developer mode) instead.

Here is my `webpack.config.js`:

```js
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.(jsx)$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: "babel-loader"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    entry: {
      gallery: './src/react/presentational/gallery.jsx'
    },
    output: {
      filename: '[name].js',
      path: __dirname + '/public/js'
    },
    resolve: {alias: {root: path.resolve('.')}}
  }
```

My `.babelrc`:

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/react"],
}
```

I've tried implementing various combinations of the following dependencies, and then some:

```
"@babel/core": "^7.7.4",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^7.7.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.7.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.7.4",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
```

I've tried multiple tutorials on how to set this up, and it just doesn't seem to be working. One thing to note, is I'm not trying to use the transpiler to write the html, just to generate the react js file, which is then imported into a pug file. (note, I've thought about using the `type="text/babel"` method to import the jsx directly, but that won't work, b/c I'm `import`ing data into the js file, so the import into the pug file needs to be `type="module"`.)

UPDATE: screenshot
[image]

Comment: What specifically are the long strings? Without knowing what you're seeing it's very hard to answer this.

Comment: @loganfsmyth I've added a screenshot. On the right you can see after a handful of functions, it's just a solid block of code...why would that much be needed for something so simple?

Comment: As the comment says, that code is from the `object-assign` module. That module is a dependency of React itself, so when you bundle up React, that is expected behavior.

Comment: @loganfsmyth yeah that's exactly what I was looking for. I didn't realize I was bundling React into the output itself, and I don't need it since I'm importing the react frame as a script elsewhere. Thank you!

Comment: @loganfsmyth do you know if there is a way to transpile the file without bundling the imports into the file itself?

Comment: Can you delete the `import`s entirely? If you're loading React via a script tag, you can access the global directly and don't need the import.

Comment: @loganfsmyth sorry, I should have clarified, I don't care about importing the react, yes I can remove those statement, but there is raw data, I'm trying to keep separate (SoC), so I am importing the raw data, and I don't want to have to transpile each time I update the raw data.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand you mean by "raw data".

Comment: @loganofsmyth this is ultimately going to be for my portfolio. The gallery is a list of my projects with links to the code and a demo. The react presents the projects, but it importd the data for those projects (like the project's name, url, link to the source code etc...) from another file, and as I create more projects, I would like to be able to add to the project data without having to retranspiling.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203645/discussion-between-loganfsmyth-and-tara-stahler).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output here is expected because your application uses React. The code you are seeing is extra code that is part of React itself.

Additionally, it shows up extra-ugly because it is wrapped in an `eval`, which you can see in your screenshot. This is because, while it makes the code itself ugly, it is the best default because it is a good balance of keeping bundling faster as your project gets bigger and bigger, and keeping your application bundled in such a way that browser devtools can easily allow you to debug your code as if you were looking at the original un-bundled code. If you run Webpack with the argument `--production`, it will not have the `eval` anymore, though it will be unreadable because Webpack will then enable minification, sooo, best not to worry about what the code output by Webpack actually looks like really.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what version of webpack you are using, and do not see the `long strings of code` you said.

I guess the bundling was considered as production rather than development mode and the code was minified.

Have you tried to specify the the mode as `development` or turn off optimization in webpack.config.js in 3 ways, like

1.

```
module.exports = {
   mode: 'development',
   entry: ....
}
```

or 2. 
`process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development';` in webpack.config.js

or 3. turn off the optimization with `optimization.minimize = false;` in webpack.config.js

Do not hesitate to try any combination of the 3 ways.

Comment: I've added a screenshot. Here's the verions I'm using: `"webpack": "^4.41.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10"` The script I used was `webpack --mode development`

Comment: Well, from the screenshot, it is not minified, then the 3rd way does not work. Can you console.log("process.env.NODE_ENV "+process.env.NODE_ENV) in webpack.config.js. And you also can try to add ```devtool: 'inline-source-map'``` in webpack.config.js.